# I am trying to set up a new website with Foundation scss, although, every time i try running sass this error comes up

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to set up a new website with Foundation scss, althogh, every time i try running sass this error comes up

Compilation Error
Error: File "/Users/juri/lastHope/a/scss/util/util" not found
on line 63 of Users/juri/lastHope/a/scss/_settings.scss
from line 3 of sass/Users/juri/lastHope/a/scss/app.scss
>> @import 'util/util';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem.

You have to set the `includePaths` for the sass compiler, use `~foundation-sites/scss/util/util` (if you use webpack) or remove the line.

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-zurb-template/blob/4492303cfb6a05c60f74cb412247fa5f1e619ec8/gulpfile.babel.js#L96

```js
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: PATHS.sass
    })
```

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-zurb-template/blob/147c65c2690e8099ae93432459bfd1a57fcdbbbe/config.yml#L22-L24

```yaml
  sass:
    - "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"
    - "node_modules/motion-ui/src"
```

https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths

> includePaths
> Type: Array
> Default: []
> An array of paths that LibSass can look in to attempt to resolve your @import declarations. When using data, it is recommended that you use this.